# Mapkit Annotation custom images are not changing

Tags: ios, swift3, mapkit

Hello I'm currently working on stylizing my map on my app and I want to change the images of the pins on the map. I've read tutorials on how to implement this change but for some reason it is not working in my app. Can anyone help me figure out why it is not changing?

My map's delegate is already linked to self.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let identifier = "hai"
    if annotation is shots {
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
            let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
            annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "ip.png")!
        } else {

            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }

        return annotationView
    }
    return nil
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)` instead of `MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)`. Thats what the method returns.

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch. Cant believe i spent hours on this.